# signalr sample doesn't work when built using x64 configuration

Tags: c#, 64-bit, signalr

I just downloaded the SignalR Ticker Sample and build and run it, works great! and then build it using x64 and removed the original AnyCPU from the config.  It stops working.  The error in the console of the browser window is:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
SignalR.StockTicker.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

I am using .net 4.5.  I need to build using x64 due to compatibility wth other libraries.

Please advice.

Comment: The sample can be downloaded from:https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR-StockTicker

Comment: You dont have to build in x64 mode, do you? AnyCPU will do just fine. Whether the app will be 32-bit, is an IIS setting.

Comment: leppie,  please elaborate?  I want to like to 64 bit dlls eventually.  SO you are saying I can built using Any CPU?  If so,  what are the setting on IIS that I have to make to make sure this works?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think I realize what the problem is now.  VS2013 is launching IIS EXpress in 32 bit mode by default:  I think this fixed the problem:Add the registry key. Go to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\WebProjects
Add new key of type “DWORD (32-bit) Value”

Name: Use64BitIISExpress Value: 1

Comment: that doesn't solve it either!

Answer (score 0):

This problem existed because IIS Express looks at the bin directory for DLLs and this behavior cannot be overridden using the probing tag as claimed by the IIS documentation.  I have reported this a bug to Microsoft.

In other words,  the output path for the bin in the project setting cannot be changed to anything other than bin  for you to be able to debug your program within Visual Studio which uses IIS Express by default.

I wasted a lot of time on this.  Hope it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Can you add a link to your bug report with Microsoft?  Others with similar will want to vote it up.